# Why my listview inside fragment is not filtering

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am implementing search functionality inside one of my fragment activity which consists of a listview. I need implement searching in my listview but it doesn't work. I have searched a lot but can't find anything appropriate. Finally i have used the following code but with no luck.

My activity code looks like this.

```
public class ActivityFragment extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText searchEditText;
    String editTextInput;
    Task task;
    ListGettersSetters listGettersSetters;
    ListAdapter listAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> listViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        task = new Task();
        task.execute(userId, userToken);

        searchEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
        searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence characterSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                editTextInput = searchEditText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                listAdapter.filter(editTextInput);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence characterSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
        });

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                ListGettersSetters listGettersSettersItem = (ListGettersSetters) listAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TERM", listGettersSettersItem ().toLowerCase());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Task extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {

                if (result != null) {
                    JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
                    JSONArray getAllJSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                    for (i = 0; i < getAllJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject allJSONObject = getAllJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        listGettersSetters = new SelectAGiftGettersSetters(name, imageUrl);

                        listGettersSetters .setName(allJSONObject .getString("name"));
                        listGettersSetters .setImageUrl(allJSONObject .getString("background"));

                        listViewArrayList.add(listGettersSetters);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_row, listViewArrayList);

            if (listViewArrayList.size() > 0) {
                setListAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No data found...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And following is my adapter code.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListGettersSetters> {
    ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> arrayListGettersSetters;
    List<ListGettersSetters> listGettersSetters = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Context context;
    int Resource;

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView nameTextView;
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> listGettersSetters) {
        super(context, resource, listGettersSetters);
        this.listGettersSetters = listGettersSetters;
        Resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.arrayListGettersSetters = new ArrayList<ListGettersSetters>();
        this.arrayListGettersSetters.addAll(listGettersSetters);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListGettersSetters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListGettersSetters getItem(int position) {
        return arrayListGettersSetters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ListGettersSetters listGettersSetters = arrayListGettersSetters.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(listGettersSetters.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void filter(String characterText)
    {
        characterText = characterText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        listGettersSetters.clear();
        if (characterText.length() == 0)
        {
            listGettersSetters.addAll(arrayListGettersSetters);
        }
        else
        {
            for (ListGettersSetters listGettersSetters : arrayListGettersSetters)
            {
                if (listGettersSetters.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(characterText));
                {
                    listGettersSetters.add(listGettersSetters);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: In your  `public void filter(String characterText)` you are filtering `listGettersSetters` while in your `public int getCount()` you are getting the number of elements of `arrayListGettersSetters`. You should use the same arraylist for `public int getCount()`, `public View getView(...)` and your `public void filter(...)`. Also, consider too to implement Filtereable (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) instead of your own filter, since the one from the SDK filters in background and doesn't stuck the UI.

Comment: i have tried with adding arrayListGettersSetters in the else part of filter method but the listview got totally dissapear. Could you post the edited code of mine.